# Unable to use customized color in TableView separator

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a tableView with more than one section in it. For applying a color on each section's outline I am using the following code in viewDidLoad:

```
[tableView setSeparatorColor: [UIColor blueColor]];
```

Now, I need to apply a customized color in the section outline for which i am using:

```
[tableView setSeparatorColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: r green: g blue: b alpha:1]];
```

But it shows white color instead. I am unable to use this customized color. Plz help!

o_O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, be sure that the `r`, `g` and `b` variable are floats in the range `[0,1]`. Then everything should work fine.

#### Edit

To be able to use RGB values you should change your code this way:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:1]
```

so that you can set `r`, `g` and `b` in the `[0,255]` range.

Comment: For example, [UIColor colorWithRed:200/255 green:33/255 blue:50/255 alpha:1];

Comment: You are diving integers here, hence `220/255 = 1` in `Objective-C`. Try with: `220/255.0` for example.